# Use model data in in a service after it was saved by another service.

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an Index controller that gets user data and saves it to a model in my application. This happens during the "CustomAuth" call below.

```
[CustomAuth(group = "Role-View")]
public class IndexController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            //call to progService
            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Error.Log(e, log.LogGuid, this.User.Identity.Name);
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code I am using to assign things to my model.

```
public void CheckForUser(string username, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, string phoneNumber)
    {
        var userDataModel = new UserDataModel();
        userDataModel.username = username;
        userDataModel.firstName = firstName; 
        userDataModel.lastName = lastName;
        userDataModel.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        userDataModel.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;

        var userexists = db.PARTies.Any(x => x.ABBR_NM == username);
        if (userexists)
        {
            var updateUser = db.PARTies.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ABBR_NM == username);
            //Get and assign the partId to the model. 
            userDataModel.partyId = updateUser.PARTY_ID;
            //Update any fields that are relevant.
            updateUser.FIRST_NM = userDataModel.firstName;
            updateUser.LAST_NM = userDataModel.lastName;
            updateUser.ABBR_NM = userDataModel.username;
            updateUser.FULL_NM = (userDataModel.firstName + " " + userDataModel.lastName);
            //Save the updated Data to the database. 
            db.SaveChanges();
```

My issue is that once this is complete, I can't seem to access the user data again. I would like to call my database and use the userDataModel.partyId from the model like so. (In a service in my Business Layer.)

```
public List<WizardProgModel> FetchTable()
{
    return db.WIZARD_PRGRSS.Where(x => x.PARTY_ID == userDataModel.partyId);
}
```

I am probably missing something dumb here but shouldn't I be able to reference anything I assign in my model while the application is running? Everything up to this point is server side so the View shouldn't come into play at this point.

Thank you.

Comment: you need to look at variable scope.. `userDataModel` only exists in `CheckForUser` method and not available outside of that context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare the model to save it as a new db entity just use the parameters from you method directly and once in your service simply go fetch the entity back from the db. and if you need it as a model in the service fetch it like so:

```
var userModel = db.PARTies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ABBR_NM == username).Select(e => new  = UserDataModel {
username = username,
firstName = firstName,
lastName = lastName,
emailAddress = emailAddress,
phoneNumber = phoneNumber
});
```

Make your read method accept the Party Id as a parameter, For how you will get it to the service I can't tell you because I simply don't have the scope of your application/solution.

```
public List<WizardProgModel> FetchTable(int partyId)
{
    return db.WIZARD_PRGRSS.Where(x => x.PARTY_ID == partyId);
}
```

Comment: Passing the parameter in was the the answer that worked. I was hoping to find a way to use variables without passing them and also not setting them to static. This does work though. Thank you.